# how to prevent Google from indexing the div placeholder for swfobject?

Tags: flash, seo, swfobject

I'm using swfobject, and in the replacement div I have a message for those who don't have Flash or JS support.

The replacement div contains a message like "You don't have Flash player, please download here" - my concern here, is that Google will see and index this message, which is not relevant to the content of the page, and it's going to affect the search ranking.

Is there some way to mark a piece of content to be ignored by Google? My guess is no.

But then how do you go about placing a message like this without having it indexed?

My only idea is to use an iframe with nofollow. But then Google will penalize any site that uses frames, so that's not a good option either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, the best option at this time seems to be to insert the message using JavaScript - I conclude that you can't get around the JS dependency.

Other posts suggest that Google is pretty good at identifying this type of message and ignoring it - so it may not be a big deal after all.

Answer (score 1):

never tried this before but you could try and use googleon/googleoff

see link for more info.

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/ViewC8614968-56ED-4729-9C12-F01677DAC412.htm

EDIT:
Its only works for Google enterprise search. Sorry

Comment: Very cool if that works.  I was under the impression it was an all or nothing when it came to indexing a page's content.

Comment: Shame it does not work for internet searching. big shame really should be something they implement.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but yeah, not what I'm looking for. My best option at this time seems to be to insert that message using JavaScript - so you can't get around the JS dependency, as far as I could find. However, a lot of posts indicate that Google is pretty good at identifying this type of message and ignoring it! So it may not be a big deal after all.